# where condition using encrypt table fields in laravel?

Tags: laravel, encryption

I have some fields on data base with **encrypt form**.
I want to use that encrypt field in where condition.
any way to use **where condition** with encrypt table fields in **laravel**?

this code are in model.

```php
$wherecondition = "";

$title = 0;
$employees = employee::select('*');
$wherecondition = $employees->where('delFlg', 0)
    ->where('resign_id', 0)
    ->where(Crypt::decrypt('title'), $title);
// here title is encrypt form on table
// here $title is a fix variable
$employees = $wherecondition;
$employees = $employees->orderBy($request->employeesort, $request->sortOrder)
    ->paginate($request->plimit);
```

Comment: Can you show your code and sample data in DB?

Comment: Provide more data

Comment: I am edited my code.
title is encrypt form on table.
This title original value is 2.
I want to use title in where condition.

Comment: Just curious - why not just encrypt the title, and then find the $employees where encrypted title is equal to the also encrypted title in DB? If this works like hashes, that should be suffitient to find the data you need?

Comment: Yes its very curious.
Because my client want to encrypt full data base.
so i want to try like this.

Comment: @krishnaragav, that doesnt change my point. What im suggesting doesnt change the fact that the db is encrypted.